# XSLT tokenize or split text with empty fixed length whitespaces?

Tags: xslt, text, whitespace, tokenize

Scenario:

I have an element containing 6 text values.

```
<e1>A B C D E F</e1>
```

`A,B,...,F` are multiple character fixed length string.

I want to map these 6 text values to  6 different elements like

```
<v1>A</v1>............<v6>F</v6>
```

My XSLT contains the following logic:

```
<xsl:variable name="vTokens">
            <TokenValue>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="str:tokenize(.,' ' )"/>
            </TokenValue> 
</xsl:variable>

<v1>
<xsl:value-of select="$vTokens/TokenValue/token[1]"/>
</v1>
<v6>
<xsl:value-of select="$vTokens/TokenValue/token[2]"/>
</v6>
```

Problem:

Any of these text values can be empty but it will be a fixed length NULL string of whitespace; for example, A can be a 14 character NULL string, which messes with the delimiter in `tokenize`. So if B is missing, element `<v2>` will contain C in the final output and `<v6>` will not even exist.

So if B/C/D/E is missing in input, the result never contains `<v6>` element and wrong values are placed in all other elements except `<v1>`.

Comment: Apologize for the typo in "Element will contain c in final ourput and will not even exist" I mean to say  Element V2 will contain C in final output and element V6 will not even exist.

Comment: "*A,B..F are multiple character fixed length string.*" Do we know the length of this string? If yes, why don't you use the substring() function to extract the values?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 2.0 here, or the XSLT 1.0 with an extension function (EXSLT)?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
<xsl:variable name="s" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to string-length($s) div $N">
  <token><xsl:value-of select="substring($s, ., $N)"/></token>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I believe `str:tokenize()` indicates that OP is using XSLT 1.0 (probably Xalan-J or libxslt).